# I can't migrate drupal to my local server

Tags: php, mysql, apache, drupal, localhost

I need to build a development environment on my computer for a drupal project with code from other developers to improve it.
I edited my /etc/hosts and httpd-vhosts.conf, create tables in my database with a script in phpmyadmin and change the data connection in /sites/default/settings.php but by putting page.dev:8888 in my browser, it shows me the index.php file php code
Also, when I write page.dev:8888/phpinfo.php in my browser shows me this:

```
<?php echo phpinfo (); ?>
```

My system is a mac and localserver with xampp.

I'm going crazy with this

Sorry for my English, I'm Spanish

Answer (score 1):

PHP is just not doing its job. PHP should be interpreting the script.

I am certain that you have not installed PHP right or started PHP.

Check PHP installation manuals.